# Module 'flutter_sms' not found

Tags: flutter, plugins, sms, mms

Got Module 'flutter_sms' not found build error from Xcode

[image]

Trying to use Flutter Plugin for sending SMS and MMS on Android and iOS
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sms

[image]

Got error trying to build for simulator

flutter: PlatformException(message_not_sent, Cannot send message on this device!, Cannot send SMS and MMS on a Simulator. Test on a real device., null)

[image]

Got same error when building example project for device

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sms/example

Answer (score 3):

The problem probably is not with plugin, Xcode just can't read first import so try this:

1. open a terminal and go to my_flutter_project/
2. go to my_flutter_project/ios/, delete Podfile, Podfile.lock and Pods/
3. go back to my_flutter_project/ and do: flutter clean
4. fluter build ios

if this won't work check if  iOS Deployment Target for the Runner project matches with your Pods targets

Comment: Titas,   it works, thanks very much.   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1at556cK6Tot5Lg8ZcSRaBnwDMbkvgq4J/view?usp=sharing

Comment: trying to give you a up vote but they wont let me. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HqKzVjI148I5AM1wabLD5YMLfjSF3Y_n/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iV5kaNYDjzBbl2dTIXVj6Z0o7D7oKzHf/view?usp=sharing.   Tested text by texting to myself

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```